# Stop Screenly Raspberry Pi from turning off screen

Tags: linux, debian

I have set up some Raspberry Pi's in my corporation with [`Screenly`](https://www.screenlyapp.com/) inside. It has simple overlay to show a webpage with some slides.

My problem is the screensaver that turns on when I'm not at work. I tried to add a reboot command to the `crontab`, edit boot settings with screensaver, etc.

When testing it for few (6-8) hours, the screen never turns black, but overnight when I'm gone, the screen turns black. What can I do to stop this?

Answer (score 1):

There was a similar question [posted on the Raspberry Pi StackExchange](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/752/how-do-i-prevent-the-screen-from-going-blank).

There they suggest installing `x11-xserver-utils` (with `apt-get install`), and adding these lines to your `~/.xinitrc` file:

> ```
> xset s off         # don't activate screensaver
> xset -dpms         # disable DPMS (Energy Star) features.
> xset s noblank     # don't blank the video device
> ```

Restart X, and your problem should be solved.